# Flash ActionScript 3.0 Typewriter Dialiouge Box

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, dialog

So This may be a very simple answer, but I cannot figure this out. I am making a game where the dialogue box has this typewriter effect and I want the text to change as it enters another frame. (textF is my instance name for the dynamic text box).

```
var myString:String = "Howdy Howdy Howdy Howdy\n\n Howdy";
var myArray:Array = myString.split("")
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);
function frameLooper(event:Event): void {
    if (myArray.length > 0) {
        textF.appendText(myArray.shift());
    }
    else {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);
    }
}
```

Now I want to change the text from "Howdy..." to like "And then the sun rises in the east" when it enters the next frame.

How do I code that? Thanks to anyone who can answer this... and if I'm confusing, I could reword this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways you can do this. Since you are using an `ENTER_FRAME` event, here's a relative working example:

```
//Create 3 variables, 1 for your current text, time, and speed
import flash.utils.getTimer;

//remove access modifiers if you are doing this in the timeline
private var beginTime:Number;
private var currentText:String
private const SPEED:int = 100;

//set the current text and begin time, then add your listener
beginTime = getTimer();
currentText = "Howdy...And then the sun rises in the east";

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, frameLooper);

//then in your frameLooper()
function frameLooper(event:Event): void {
    //add character at index 0 of currentText
    if ( getTimer() - beginTime >= SPEED ) {
        beginTime = getTimer();
        textF.appendText( currentText.slice(0, 1) );
        currentText = currentText.substr( 1, currentText.length );
    }
}
```

You can adjust the `SPEED` constant to whatever you like. This is just one way of doing it with your current idea using `ENTER_FRAME` event.

Also if you want a more realistic type writer effect, you could make `SPEED` a non constant variable, and then inside the if statement `if ( getTimer() - beginTime >= SPEED )` you could randomize the SPEED variable with:

```
SPEED = Math.floor( Math.random() * ( 200 - 100 ) + 100 );
```

That would giving you varying speeds in the range of 100-200ms which you can change around.

Comment: It looks good, but I would like to remove all the text from the previous frame when it enters the next. So on one frame the text field only reads, let's say, "Howdy", and on the next frame, it says "The sun rises in the east," (no "Howdy").

Comment: Never mind, I found out how to do so. Thanks for your help! :D